# Armadillo C++ LU decomposition

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, numeric, armadillo, decomposition

I am using the Armadillo C++ library for solving linear systems of medium/large dimensions (1000-5000 equations).

Since I have to solve different linear systems

AX=b

in which A is always the same and B changes, I would like to LU factorize A only once and reuse the LU factorization with different b. Unfortunately I do not know how to perform this kind of operations in Armadillo.

What I did was just the LU factorization of the A matrix:

```
arma::mat A;
// ... fill the A matrix ...
arma::mat P,L,U;
arma::lu(L, U, P, A);
```

But now I would like to use the matrices P, L and U to solve several linear systems with different b vectors.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you have tried already? Perhaps you can edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your attempt?

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I added what I tried...

Answer (score 3):

Since `A = P.t()*L*U` (where equality is only approximate due to rounding errors), solving for `x` in `P.t()*L*U*x = b` requires to permute rows of `B` and performing forward and back substitution:

```
x = solve(trimatu(U), solve(trimatl(L), P*b) );
```

Due to the lack of a true triangular solver in armadillo, and a fast way to perform row permutation, this procedure will not be very efficient, with respect to a direct call to the relevant computational LAPACK subroutines.

General advice is to avoid explicit LU decomposition in higher level libraries, like armadillo.

1. if all different `b`'s are known at the same time, store them as columns in a rectangular matrix `B` and `X = solve(A,B);`
2. if the different `b`'s are known one at a time, then precomputing `AINV = A.i();` and `x =  AINV*b;` will be more efficient if the number of different r.h.s. vectors is big enough. See this [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/5308/1744) to a similar [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5289/1744).